# Should the complex components of react be moved to library?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react development. I'm currently using Typescript for react with webpack and npm.

i'm working on a large scale project where components are complex. As of now they are kept in certain hierachy in project folder.

i recently learn about making components library. I'm thinking of taking complex components out of project and put them in a separate component library. However, other team members say it would cauae headache to maintain library separately. since there is less to no chance of using this in any other project (thats the current situation) they should not take the components out and maintain separately.

i want to know if that is the only reason the react developers create component and  creating component to test it better and simplifing thw project complexity are not the valid reasons?